# How do I define a C# enum that includes integers as values?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm designing an application that requires a "location" field. The values for the location are "3241", "4112", "ND" and "TRAVEL", and I am trying to set up an `enum` that includes those values.

I started with

```
    enum projectLocation {3241,4112,ND,TRAVEL};
```

but the values 3241 and 4112 indicated a syntax error--`identifier expected`--for the first value in the `enum`. If I understand `enum` correctly, that's because the above statement is looking for the value for the `enum`'s integer indeces of `3241` and `4112`. Is this a correct assumption?

I tried overriding that with the following

```
    enum projectLocation {3241=0,4112,ND,TRAVEL};
```

and

```
    enum projectLocation {3241=0,4112=1,ND=2,TRAVEL=3};
```

but I'm still getting the same syntax error on the `3241` value. Interestingly though, on both of these statements, there is NO syntax error on 4112, but I get `can't find the namespace or name ND` and `...TRAVEL`

It makes sense that `enum` will not allow a mix of strings and integers, and I have two other `enum`s that work fine and are only lists of string values, corroborating that theory. Is there a way to force `enum` to accept the numeric values as strings? I've not been able to find any references in MSDNs C# documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums are called as named constants, so basically you give a name for some constant. Names are "identifiers" in c#, where identifier can contain numbers but first character cannot be a number.

You can add `_` before that to fix this error.

```
enum projectLocation 
{
    _3241=0,
    _4112=1,
    ND=2,
    TRAVEL=3
}
```

Also note the Fields, Properties Methods or whatever falls under this identifier rule mentioned above.

Comment: First Character cannot be a number. Got it! That makes sense. That's the syntax I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it exactly like you're trying to. Here's an alternative:

```
enum projectLocation {
    L3241=3241,
    L4112=4112,
    ND=2,
    TRAVEL=3
}
```

Starting them with a letter makes them valid enum identifiers, and setting their value equal to their number lets you do things like `(projectLocation)3241` and get the expected `L3241` value.

If you need the values to be `3241` and `4112` when serialized, include the proper attribute for your serialization approach, e.g. with Json.NET:

```
enum projectLocation {
    [JsonProperty("3241")]
    L3241=3241,
    [JsonProperty("4112")]
    L4112=4112,
    ND=2,
    TRAVEL=3
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to do something like this:

```
enum projectLocation { v3241, v4112, ND, TRAVEL };
```

or:

```
enum projectLocation { _3241, _4112, ND, TRAVEL };
```

My preference would be the use of the underscore.

Comment: Is this just adding a string character as the first character of the value to force c# to recognize the value as a string or are these some sort of reserved characters I don't know about? Since the numbers represent two different building addresses...the 3241 Building and the 4112 Building, `3241BLDG` and `4112BLDG` would be data values more relevant to the client.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not allow the first character of member names to start with a number.  Consider using the `@` character as a prefix, or some other character that conveys a meaning useful to a reader of the code as a number in isolation may not be very intuitive to a reader not familiar with the significance of `3241` in your context.

Comment: `@` has a [special meaning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx) and doesn't work here as in `@3241`.

Comment: @TimS Ah, you're right, I didn't actually know this. I thought it worked for all member names.  Well I learned something new today then!  I'd never come across this before, as like I suggested I'd circumvent the problem myself by using an descriptive English name for the enumeration member in the first place.

Comment: For this particular client, 3241 and 4112 are the names they use for two separate buildings, and are very meaningful for them. Based on member names not being able to start with a number (the new thing ~I~ learned today), "BLDG3241" and "BLDG4112" will be the enum member names.